# How to i remove a folder from my project in git for good?

Tags: git, git-svn

How to i remove a folder from my project in git for good?

I keep deleted this folder and I want it removed from the repo

but it keeps coming back... how do I tell git to remove a folder for good

Answer (score 0):

Delete the files using `git rm` and push a commit with these changes. You still have to delete the empty directory afterwards, because git only works on files, not directories.

Comment: Mentioning SVN certainly makes a difference. I have no idea how SVN works, sorry.